# Getting scrollyspy to trigger events based on window location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a script so that an animation triggers when the user scrolls down to an element.

Here's the script (it's located right before the `</body>` tag)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        //activate scrollspy
        $('#rect-container').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
            console.log("SCROLLSPY: ENTER");
            var squares = new Array();
            squares[0] = $("#top-left");
            squares[1] = $("#top-right");
            squares[2] = $("#bottom-left");
            squares[3] = $("#bottom-right");
            for(var a=0; a<4; a++)
                squares[a].animate({height:"100%"}, Math.random()*1500+500);

        });
        $("#rect-container").scrollSpy();
</script>
```

The `"#rect-container"` element is a `<ul>` with 4 li elements.  It is located after a full page-sized div.  The script, for reason, executes as soon as the page loads.  Any ideas?

This is the version of scrollspy I have

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy/master/scrollspy.js

Comment: Your title is very poor. Describe the problem in it to set your question apart from others.

Comment: thanks for your advice; i updated it

Comment: That's a bit better thanks